# How to NOT compile for X11 OpenGL on Windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, mingw, glfw

I'm on windows and I'm trying to open a blank window using OpenGL and C++. I'm using CMake (`cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles"`) to compile the project. My main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 450

int main ()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW NOT INITIALIZED" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "OpenGL Window", 0, 0);

    if (!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "WINDOW WASN'T CREATED" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (1)
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(window.exe)

add_subdirectory(glfw/)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glfw)
```

The `Makefile` generates just fine, however when I run it, I get the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindX11.cmake:457 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  glfw/src/CMakeLists.txt:187 (find_package)
```

I'm aware that X11 only works on Unix-style systems, however I'm wondering if there's any way I compile the project for Windows, instead of X11. Or somehow run the X11 app on Windows.

### EDIT:

It turns out that I had to use `cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"` using the `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` MSYS2 package in the `mingw64` shell. And use `mingw-w64-x86_64-make` (instead of `make`) to compile it. The `cmake` package and the `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` packages are not the same.

Comment: Set `GLFW_BUILD_X11` variable to OFF and set to ON a variable suitable for your windows system. E.g. `GLFW_BUILD_WIN32`. (While you are debugging building of GLFW, it is simpler to build this library standalone. After you will be managed to build it successfully, you could build it as embedded into your project.)

Comment: Unrelated: `cmake --build` is your friend for building regardless of which build system is being used

Comment: For faster builds use Ninja (https://ninja-build.org/) instead by using CMake flag `-GNinja`. It's a lot faster than Make and the command is the same on Windows as on other platforms.